# ssh login in Bash script

Tags: ssh, authentication

I've been working on a series of scripts to perform tasks on my remote server, but have gotten stuck at how to log in via ssh mid script, as I cannot enter the password automatically. Is there a way to do so?

echo "logging in.. \n"
ssh username@IP
somehow hardcode in password
nextCommand

Comment: You can set up public key authentication without a passphrase, or you can use an authentication agent. I would suggest the latter if it is reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to send the password via parameter.
You can use ssh keys.
In your client machine:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

This will create a file with your public ssh key on your ~/.ssh/ named id_rsa.pub
Then, you must add the content of the **id_rsa.pub** file on your server machine (you can copy it via scp or ftp), and run something like:

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/.authorized_keys
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

As @MichaelKjörling said, set up public key authentication:

```
ssh-copy-id user@host
```

Now you can `ssh` to that `user@host` without a password.